# Transform FormRecognizer output in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-form-recognizer

I want to Extract tables in PDF file and insert that data into output sink ( CSV \ Azure SQL etc )

I have tried below things

1. Analyze custom pdf document using Form Recognizer General document as I just want to scrape Tables
2. Call "Get Analyze Result" REST API from ADF to get Table Array

Now I want to loop through every Table and Cells and insert data into Azure SQL table

How do I achieve this effectively ?

One way I see is , use JSON parsing along with Looping mechanism in ADF to transform Form Recognizer output row by row

Note : I have checked this post already
[Extract PDF table data using Azure Form Recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895644/extract-pdf-table-data-using-azure-form-recognizer)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using the cognitive services API with the external call transformation: https://youtu.be/r22nthp-f4g?t=400

Comment: Instead of calling Azure Cognitive API , what if I call Form Recognizer API directly ?